# How to flash a cable modem with custom firmware?

Tags: networking, firmware

I'm looking into getting my own cable modem for use with Comcast and would like to load it with custom firmware. Is there a modem equivalent of DD-WRT? I've heard of something called Haxorware, but their [website](http://www.haxorware.com/) isn't very descriptive. Also, on Wi-Fi devices, custom firmware lets you do things like adjust transmit power and configure VPNs and all that whatnot, but what would custom firmware do on a cable router? Are only specific modems compatible?

TL;DR;

1)Is there custom firmware for modems?
2)What are some good custom firmware programs?
3)What are the benefits as opposed to default firmware?
4)What are some good cable modems to get for custom firmware?